# How can I automatically start an application after login in Kde4

Tags: linux, debian, kde, kde-4

I am using Kde 4.4 and I would like to start one of the applications automatically after every login to the system. How can I configure it? I remember I managed to find a dialog window in one of the previous versions, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Settings → Advanced → Autostart

If you forget where a thing is, use the search widget at the top of the application.

Comment: Cheers! There must be a bug in 4.4, because it doesn't always start even though it was configured